# Drawing circles around points in a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, border, matlab-figure

I have two matrices

```
timeline =  [0.0008    0.0012    0.0016    0.0020    0.0024    0.0028];
```

Origdata =

```
   79.8400   69.9390   50.0410   55.5082   34.5200   37.4486   31.4237   27.3532   23.2860   19.3039
   79.7600   69.8193   49.8822   55.3115   34.2800   37.1730   31.1044   26.9942   22.8876   18.9061
   79.6800   69.6996   49.7233   55.1148   34.0400   36.8975   30.7850   26.6352   22.4891   18.5084
   79.6000   69.5799   49.5645   54.9181   33.8000   36.6221   30.4657   26.2762   22.0907   18.1108
   79.5200   69.4602   49.4057   54.7215   33.5600   36.3467   30.1464   25.9173   21.6924   17.7133
   79.4400   69.3405   49.2469   54.5249   33.3200   36.0714   29.8271   25.5584   21.2941   17.3159
```

When I plot them, I get a graph like below.

```
plot(timeline, Origdata, '.');
```

[image]

How can I draw a circle of radius 0.3524 value around each point? This radius should be relative to the **y-axis only**.

Comment: If you draw a circle of that radius, it is much larger than your x-axis and will by far exceed the range. Your values on the x-axis are between 0.0008 and 0.00028

Comment: I know it is not what you asked for, but if your circle is only related to the y-axis as I understand now, I would use bars instead: `errorbar(repmat(timeline.',1,size(Orgidata,2)),Orgidata,0.3524*ones(size(Orgidata)),'.')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily using [`viscircles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/viscircles.html) (which requires the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/)) however I don't think that the output is actually what you're expecting.

```
radius = 0.3524;
dots = plot(timeline, Origdata, '.');

hold on

for k = 1:numel(dots)
    plotdata = get(dots(k));
    centers = [plotdata.XData(:), plotdata.YData(:)];

    % Ensure the the colors match the original plot
    color = get(dots(k), 'Color');

    viscircles(centers, radius * ones(size(centers(:,1))), 'Color', color);
end
```

[image]

The reason that it looks like this is because your X data is *very* close together relative to your y data and for circles to appear as circles, I have forced the x and y scaling of the axes to be equal (`axis equal`)

**Edit**

If you only want the `radius` to be relative to the y axis (distance) then we actually need to draw ellipses with an x and y radius. We want to scale the "x-radius" to make it appear as a circle regardless of your true axes aspect ratio, something like this can actually do that.

The trick to the code below is setting the data and plot aspect ratios (`pbaspect` and `daspect`) to manual. This ensures that the aspect ratio of the axes doesn't change during zoom, resizing, etc and makes sure that our "circles" remain circular-looking.

```
dots = plot(timeline, Origdata, '.');

drawnow

% Force the aspect ratio to not change (keep the circles, as circles)
pbaspect('manual')
daspect('manual')

hold on

aspectRatio = daspect;

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
t(end+1) = NaN;

radius = 4.3524;

% Scale the radii for each axis
yradius = radius;
xradius = radius * aspectRatio(1)/aspectRatio(2);

% Create a circle "template" with a trailing NaN to disconnect consecutive circles
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
t(end+1) = NaN;
circle = [xradius*cos(t(:)), yradius*sin(t(:))];

for k = 1:numel(dots)
    x = get(dots(k), 'XData');
    y = get(dots(k), 'YData');
    color = get(dots(k), 'Color');

    % Center circle template at all points
    circles = arrayfun(@(x,y)bsxfun(@plus, [x,y], circle), x, y, 'uni', 0);
    circles = cat(1, circles{:});

    plot(circles(:,1), circles(:,2), 'Color', color)
end
```

[image]

Just to demonstrate, if we increase the circle radius to 4.3524 we can see the circles better.

[image]

And this works with all resizing etc.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. How to avoid this problem. may be without axis equal.

Comment: @MayankLakhani The issue is with your data because of the axes scaling like both Daniel and I have mentioned. I have added an alternate solution to mine.

Comment: @MayankLakhani Be sure to try out the iteration I just posted as it does a better job ensuring that the circles remain circular even during zooming, panning, resizing, etc.

Comment: Warning: `viscircles` requires the image processing toolbox.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to include that. I guess that's one of many reasons I favor the second option which only relies on `plot`.

Comment: @Suever yes :) You got a vote from me anyway. This is a very good answer.  Looks like you morterboarded again!

Comment: Did that gif really need to be so dizzying? :-P

Answer (score 2):

To draw circles in MATLAB, you obviously have to use the `rectangle` function ;)

As mentioned in my comment, the size of `0.3524` does not match your axis, so I chose different sizes to have the circles actually visible, These are `rx` and `ry`

```
timeline =  [0.0008    0.0012    0.0016    0.0020    0.0024    0.0028];
Orgidata =[79.8400   69.9390   50.0410   55.5082   34.5200   37.4486   31.4237   27.3532   23.2860   19.3039
   79.7600   69.8193   49.8822   55.3115   34.2800   37.1730   31.1044   26.9942   22.8876   18.9061
   79.6800   69.6996   49.7233   55.1148   34.0400   36.8975   30.7850   26.6352   22.4891   18.5084
   79.6000   69.5799   49.5645   54.9181   33.8000   36.6221   30.4657   26.2762   22.0907   18.1108
   79.5200   69.4602   49.4057   54.7215   33.5600   36.3467   30.1464   25.9173   21.6924   17.7133
   79.4400   69.3405   49.2469   54.5249   33.3200   36.0714   29.8271   25.5584   21.2941   17.3159];
ry=1;
rx=0.0001;
dots=plot(timeline, Orgidata , '.');
hold on
for ix=1:size(Orgidata ,1)
    for jx=1:size(Orgidata ,2)
        rectangle('Position',[timeline(ix)-(rx/2),Orgidata(ix,jx)-(ry/2),rx,ry],'Curvature',[1,1],'EdgeColor',get(dots(jx), 'Color'));
    end
end
```

[image]

Comment: hi Daniel, thanks for the answer. as i have already mentioned i need a circle with radius 0.3524 value. Actually, y positin is distance and x is time.

Comment: I read that, but these sizes don't make sense with your axis. Your whole x-axis is 0.002 long, how should a circle of that size fit into your plot? You could easily put in your value, I am sure that is not what you expect.

Comment: I want t define this gate (border) only in y directin. than how can i do it?

Comment: Okay, now I understand. You can use the solution explained in the other answer: `ry=0.3524;
rx=ry/yrng*xrng;`